# Jenkins is not incorporating the jobs copied in jobs directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I installed a new Jenkins on a EC2 instance and copied the jobs directory from another Jenkins. However, Jenkins is not showing the projects on its website.
I use the directory:  *./var/lib/jenkins/jobs*
and I restart the Jenkins server using:

```
service jenkins restart
```

Also the "Reload Configuration from Disk" under "Manage Jenkins" is not working.
How can I make Jenkins to incorporate the jobs in the Jenkins *jobs* directory?

Answer (score 1):

When jobs are not showing in the all tab, usually there are exceptions in the Jenkins [logs](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/system-administration/viewing-logs/). You can have incompatible or missing plugin.
You can also see if you have copied the jobs recursively, for example, verify that config.xml of a job is present. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20758905/jenkins-job-disappeared-after-restart) and [this](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Administering+Jenkins) can help you.